# Flower Dashboard no muestra Tasks de Celery

Tags: django, docker-compose, celery

estoy aprendiendo a realizar tareas asincronas y periodicas con Celery y Django, y de momento las pruebas que he realizado han funcionado bastante bien, pudiendo ver los resultado desde los Logs de la consola. Pero al intentar ver los mismos resultados desde el Dashboard de Flower no aparece nada de nada.
Aún me cuesta entender como funcionan estos servicios, pero según entiendo en los Logs, Flower se conecta correctamente con el Broker Redis, y parece fallar al final.

Estos son los logs que me arroja Flower:

```
flower_1        | [I 201114 14:34:53 command:144] Broker: redis://redis:6379/0
flower_1        | [I 201114 14:34:53 command:147] Registered tasks: 
flower_1        |     ['celery.accumulate',
flower_1        |      'celery.backend_cleanup',
flower_1        |      'celery.chain',
flower_1        |      'celery.chord',
flower_1        |      'celery.chord_unlock',
flower_1        |      'celery.chunks',
flower_1        |      'celery.group',
flower_1        |      'celery.map',
flower_1        |      'celery.starmap',
flower_1        |      'cride.taskapp.celery.debug_task',
flower_1        |      'disable_finished_rides',
flower_1        |      'send_confirmation_email']
flower_1        | [I 201114 14:34:53 mixins:229] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
flower_1        | [W 201114 14:34:56 control:44] 'stats' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 201114 14:34:56 control:44] 'active_queues' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 201114 14:34:56 control:44] 'registered' inspect method failed
flower_1        | [W 201114 14:34:56 control:44] 'scheduled' inspect method failed
```

Estoy usando Docker Compose y estas configuraciones:

**Requeriments.txt**

```
# Celery
redis>=3.2.0
django-redis==4.10.0
celery==4.2.1
tornado>=5.0.0,<6.0.0
flower==0.9.2
```

**local.yml**

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: cride_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: cride_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: cride_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

**compose Celery-Flower**

```
celery flower \
--app=cride.taskapp \
--broker="${CELERY_BROKER_URL}" \
--basic_auth="${CELERY_FLOWER_USER}:${CELERY_FLOWER_PASSWORD}"
```

**compose Celery-Worker**

```
celery -A cride.taskapp worker -l INFO
```

**Compose Celery-Beat**

```
rm -f './celerybeat.pid'
celery -A cride.taskapp beat -l INFO
```

**Django Celery Configs**

```
# Celery
INSTALLED_APPS += ['cride.taskapp.celery.CeleryAppConfig']
if USE_TZ:
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_BROKER_URL = env('CELERY_BROKER_URL')
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = CELERY_BROKER_URL
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERYD_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 5 * 60
CELERYD_TASK_SOFT_TIME_LIMIT = 60

# Celery
CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES = True
```

Muchas gracias de antemano!